# Finding the Laurent Series expansion in positive and negative powers

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, laurent-series, cauchy-integral-formula

Expand the function 
\begin{equation*}
    f(z)=\frac{z}{1+z^{3}}
\end{equation*}
a) in a series of positive powers and b) in a series of negative powers. In each case, specify the region in which the expansion is valid.

I feel like I'm missing something obvious here because I don't even know where to start i.e. I don't know what annulus to consider for this problem, or how to apply the formula given:
\begin{equation*}
    a_{n}=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int _{C_{R}} \frac{f(\zeta)}{\zeta^{n+1}} d\zeta 
\end{equation*}
if $n\geq 0$ and 
\begin{equation*}
    a_{n}=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int _{C_{r}} \frac{f(\zeta)}{\zeta^{n+1}} d\zeta 
\end{equation*}
if $n< 0$. What would my $C_{R}$ and $C_{r}$ be in this case? Any help would be appreciated and I'm sorry if my wording is confusing. Thanks so much!

Comment: Those Laurent series are supposed to be be centered *where*?

Comment: It doesn't specify, that's partly why I find this confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\lvert z\rvert<1$, then $|z^3|=|z|^3<1$ and then\begin{align}\frac z{1+z^3}&=z(1-z^3+z^6-z^9+\cdots)\\&=z-z^4+z^7-z^{10}+\cdots\end{align}And, if $\lvert z\rvert>1$, then\begin{align}\frac z{1+z^3}&=-z\left(\frac1{z^3}-\frac1{z^6}+\frac1{z^9}-\cdots\right)\\&=-\frac1{z^2}+\frac1{z^5}-\frac1{z^8}+\cdots\end{align}

Comment: Thanks! Could you give a little insight into how you got there?

Comment: I just used the fact that$$\frac1{1-z}=\begin{cases}1+z+z^2+z^3+\cdots&\text{ if }\lvert z\rvert<1\\-z^{-1}-z^{-2}-z^{-3}-z^{-4}-\cdots&\text{ if }\lvert z\rvert>1.\end{cases}$$

Comment: Forgive me if this is obvious, but how to you get from $\frac{1}{1-z}$ to $\frac{z}{1+z^{3}}$? Partial fractions gives $\frac{z}{1+z^{3}}=\frac{1}{3}(\frac{z+1}{z^{2}-z+1}-\frac{1}{z+1})$ so I'm unsure where I could use that fact.

Comment: If, say, $\lvert z\rvert<1$, then $\lvert-z^3\rvert<1$ too and therefore\begin{align}\frac1{1+z^3}&=\frac1{1-(-z^3)}\\&=1+(-z^3)+(-z^3)^2+(-z^3)^3+\cdots\\&=1-z^3+z^6-z^9+\cdots\end{align}and therefore\begin{align}\frac z{1+z^3}&=z\times(1-z^3+z^6-z^9+\cdots)\\&=z-z^4+z^7-z^{10}+\cdots\end{align}